# Отправка идентификатора пользователя по нажатии на кнопку

Tags: jquery, javascript, php, mysql

Подскажите, как можно написать, приведите, пожалуйста, пример функции (ajax), которая при нажатии на кнопку отправляет PHP-скрипту идентификатор пользователя. PHP скрипт добавляет значение (имя авторизованного пользователя и имя пользователя, на страницу которого он зашел) в базу. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @raptor96, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.post('script.php', {id: 1}); // jQuery
```

На PHP:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$username;
$a_username;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`username`, `a_username`) VALUES ('{$username}', {$a_username})");
?>
```

Comment: Так

    Callback.
    $.post('script.php', {id: 1}, function(data) {
        element = $('#status');
        element.html('Успешно');
        setTimeOut(function(){
        element.hide();
    }, 5000); // 5000 - через сколько милисекунд нужно, чтоб сообщение пропало
    });